# bootstrap datepicker js disable future dates

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want disable future dates only on bootstrap datepicker.I had tried but can't resolve this problem.Anybody help!

This is my code

```
ready = function(){
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
      endDate: '+0d',
      autoclose: true
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: if possible plz provide a fiddle.

Comment: are you using jQuerymobile ?

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails and not it use jquerymobile

Answer (score 4):

try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

Comment: this code also tried not working.i have use this bootstrap datepicker plugin in ruby on rails.Any updated bootstrap datepicker js file link plz send me.

Comment: have you checked error in console ? Saying that code is not working doesn't make any sense.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion.i checked this code on console and i got this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined'.How do solve this problem i don't know but i ill try & can have any idea about this error?

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker in React JS. I have used type="date" for the date of birth and i do not want user to be able to select current or future dates. How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is to declare a variable to hold the current date then use that in the code as the date. so below is what you need to do

```
    <script>
 var date = new Date();
        var d = new Date();        
        d.setDate(date.getDate());
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: d,       
    });
});

</script>
```

With this, you are sure of what you want